# Integrate PHP on Apache and Java on Tomcat

Tags: java, php, apache, jsp, tomcat

1) I am using

```
              a) JSP : Front-end programming language
              b) PHP : Backend Programming language
```

2) These are the two languages can be run on Apache server without the integration of Tomcat.

3) But, for enhancing the logic of website, we use JAVA as another Back-end Programming language.

4) Now, this JAVA need to be integrated with the JSP and PHP pages of website.

5) So, in one JSP file, a part of the code can be in JAVA and part of the code can be in PHP.

6) Ideally, it would be great if the part of PHP code runs on Apache server and Java code runs on Tomcat server.

7) Else, please let me know to find an integration of PHP servlet which can use to run PHP code on Tomcat server.

Comment: You can have both JSP pages and PHP pages. You probably won't be able to mix the two in one file, without hacking some kind of streaming proxy (which is not easy).  The easiest solution I would think is simply having the apache handler point to tomcat for JSP files and the php handler for PHP files.  You can make them "talk" to each other to some extent although a shared session object would be more challenging.

Comment: Also you can use JSP or PHP as both front and backend, and it probably would be simpler to deal with as it is in a common code base

Comment: thanks @MiltoxBeyond i thought of sorting this out using Apache server as front-end server and Tomcat as a proxy-backend server both running in different ports. (single port integration) will this work?

Comment: Yeah it would work using virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't run in Tomcat; it gets run by an Apache module (if you're using Apache!)

JSP and Java will run in Tomcat.  JSP won't run bare-metal in Apache.

There are a few ways to get Tomcat integrated into Apache.

In terms of what you seem to want to do- I would look at implementing it all in either in php or java/jsp.

If you can't do that, then you *could* implement some REST like services in php or java and call them from the other system.  This actually might be a good thing if you want to scale things really big, but while things aren't really big(tm) you're going to have to manage the added complexity, not least of which are having things in completely different languages.